# calcular area e imprimir ela em outro aquivo txt no python

Tags: python

tenho um arquivo area.txt:

```
quadrado;2
retangulo;2;3
```

quero criar outro arquivo txt para que fique assim:

```
quadrado;2;4
retangulo;2;3;6
```

eu fiz da seguinte maneira mas ta errado:

```
arq=open('area.txt','r')
conteudo=arq.readlines()
arq.close()

for item in conteudo:
    item=item.replace(',','.')
    a=item.split(';')
    if a[0] == 'quadrado':
        print(float(a[1])*float(a[1]))
    if a[0] == 'retangulo':
        print(float(a[1])*float(a[2]))

arq=open('novo.txt','w')
arq.writelines(conteudo)
arq.close()
```

Comment: Legal, faltou falar qual o problema, colocar o erro completo que dá, ou o resultado se for diferente do esperado. "tá errado" é muito vago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problema

Olá Matheus, pelo que entendi você quer criar um novo arquivo inserindo uma nova coluna utilizando os parâmetros da sua forma geométrica. Caso seja um 'quadrado', você multiplica o segundo parâmetro por ele mesmo, caso seja um 'retângulo', você multiplica o segundo pelo terceiro parâmetro.

O que está errado no seu código é que você imprime o resultado da multiplicação na tela utilizando a função *print*, enquanto deveria criar uma nova lista *conteudo* contendo a nova coluna área para utilizar dentro de *arq.writelines(conteudo)*. Além disso, há alguns probleminhas no tratamento das strings. Mas vamos para a solução.

## Solução 1 - Trabalhando com Arquivos de Texto

No seu caso, você está manipulando um arquivo de texto (.txt). Isto deixa mais difícil (e chato) o trabalho de tratar os dados.

#### Primeiro abrimos o arquivo para leitura

Quando realizamos a leitura, *lines* recebe uma lista de strings, onde cada string é uma linha do documento.

```
arq = open('area.txt','r')
lines = arq.readlines()
arq.close()
```

#### Depois tratamos os dados

Iterando por esta lista, removemos o (\n) e quebramos a string pelo delimitador (;). Desta forma, *geom* é uma lista com os elementos de cada linha. Dependendo de cada forma geométrica, calculamos a área e reinserimos em *geom* utilizando *geom.append(str(area))*.

Com a lista contendo o nova informação, criamos uma nova linha (*new_line*) no mesmo padrão que lemos, ou seja, uma string com os dados separados por ponto e vírgula (;) e com o \n no final. Com a linha criada, criamos por fim a lista destas strings.

```
new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    geom = line.strip('\n').split(';')

    # quadrado
    if geom[0] == 'quadrado':
        area = float(geom[1]) * float(geom[1])
        geom.append(str(area))

    # retângulo
    else:    
        area = float(geom[1]) * float(geom[2])
        geom.append(str(area))

    new_line = ';'.join(geom) + '\n'
    new_lines.append(new_line)
```

#### Finalizamos salvando o arquivo

```
arq = open('novo.txt','w')
arq.writelines(new_lines)
arq.close()
```

#### Saída - Arquivo novo.txt

```
quadrado;2;4.0
retangulo;2;3;6.0
```

## Solução 2 - Tratando arquivo CSV

Como pudemos ver, trabalhar com strings do arquivo texto tem seus inconvenientes.Temos que quebrar manualmente as linhas em colunas, remover as quebras de linhas, etc. Assim, segue o mesmo tratamento, só que utilizando a biblioteca *csv*.

#### Arquivo de entrada - area.csv

```
quadrado;2
retangulo;2;3
retangulo;1;2
quadrado;3
```

#### Solução

```
import csv

with open('area.csv', 'r') as f, \
    open('new_area.csv', 'w') as new_f:

    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.writer(new_f, delimiter=';')

    for geom in reader:
        if geom[0] == 'quadrado':
            area = float(geom[1]) * float(geom[1])
            geom.append(str(area))
        else:
            area = float(geom[1]) * float(geom[2])
            geom.append(str(area))

        writer.writerow(geom)
```

#### Arquivo de saída - new_area.csv

```
quadrado;2;4.0
retangulo;2;3;6.0
retangulo;1;2;2.0
quadrado;3;9.0
```

## Conclusão

Se irá trabalhar com dados, prefira formatos de arquivos e uso de bibliotecas mais otimizadas para este trabalho. Irá te poupar muito tempo e esforço. Grande abraço.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Só mais uma duvida se por exemplo desse numero quebrado gostaria que ele arredondasse como faria isso?

Comment: Ao invés de converter o número utilizando float(geom[1]), basta converter utilizando int(geom[1]). O int trunca o número e permanece somente com a parte inteira.

Comment: Muito explicativa sua resposta @LeonardoBorges, parabéns.